# Executing .EXE file with subprocess.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, subprocess

I'm trying to automate a report generation with Python.

I have two variables, one holding the path to an EXE file that inserts the data for the report at the database and one that holds the arguments.

They are as following:

```
caminhoAbraciclo = r'\\157.116.105.2\kmb_sp\Marketing\Abraciclo\Emplacamentos\Abraciclo_KMB.exe'
argumentosAbraciclo = f'ABRACICLO:{str(hoje.ano)[2:3]}{str(hoje.mesnum).zfill(3)}'
resposta = subprocess.run([caminhoAbraciclo, argumentosAbraciclo])
```

When I `cd` to the EXE file directory and run it with the parameters, it works as intended, but when I try to run it by a python `subprocess`, it returns an error. This EXE file only return by command line and have no interface.

I've tried adding the EXE file to the `PATH` variable, but it also didn't work.

I'm pretty sure I can make this work with python, I just don't know how.

Comment: Instead of ```subprocess.run()``` try with ```subprocess.Popen()```

Comment: I've tried it, but it still doesn't work. I receive the same error.